# Declaring Instance Variable In View and Passing To Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am trying to conditionalize validation of fields being sent in a view by passing a variable from the view to the model so it knows which set of fields to check.

The model looks like this:

```
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :if => :registration_step?
  validates_numericality_of :primary_phone, :if => :contact_step?

  def registration_step?
    @step == :register
  end
  def contact_step?
    @step == :contact
  end
```

I'm not sure what I have to place in my view in order for everything to function properly. I've tried

`<% @step = :register %>`
and

```
<% @step = :contact %>
```

As well as some other combinations (:step, and also @step with 'register' and 'contact'. I know it's just a matter of syntax or I'm just missing one more thing in the model but I can't figure it out.`

Comment: If I add 'attr_accessor :step' to my model, then how is it properly set in the controller. step('register') throws errors for me. And @step = 'register' doesn't throw errors, but the validation doesn't trigger from the 'def registration_step?
    @step == :register
  end' in the model.

Comment: I've updated my answer in reply to your comment. See below.

Comment: Thanks so much! I got your solution working, but it won't solve my ultimate issue. I am creating a multistep input form, each subsequent step/page/form updates a record in the database and utilizes the same create/edit methods in the controller. The reason I need to conditionalize the validation is because on each view there are only a few form fields to validate. Validation fails for all fields not displayed on each step, so I need to conditionalize the validation. Your solution works but I can't redefine the step attribute because the same create method is called each time the form is saved.

Comment: Hmm, I definitely do not know what your best course of action is in that case. I'm pretty sure there are a few plugins that can help with multi-step forms, but I'm not entirely sure what their names are, or how actively developed they are.

Good luck :)

Comment: Take a look at acts_as_wizard for multi-step forms: http://blog.seesaw.it/pages/acts_as_wizard/two_minutes

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables set in a view won't make it to the model, not directly at least. The problem you are describing–the conditional part–is something we were just trying to deal with today.

I think your best bet is to have an `attr_accessor` on your model which you can set in your controller's create, update, whatever action–this is something that shouldn't be set in the view. Once in your model, you could have a method which checks the value of this attribute in your `if` conditions for validation. Definitely don't pass this as a hidden field from your form, though. You do not want to trust this sort of thing to be potentially manipulated by a user.

Reply to comment:

If you add `step` as an `attr_accessor`, in your controller, you should be able to do something like

```
@my_model = MyModel.new(params[:model])
@my_model.step = :register
if @my_model.save...
```

And, in your model, something along the lines of

```
validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :if => :registration_step?
def registration_step?
  step == :register
end
```